# How to turn packages with an install.sh into a .deb file?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install the arduino ide from a `tar` archive it happens to have an `install.sh`. I don't want to install by running it straight up because it won't show up on `apt` or `synaptic`.

(The package isn't available on a PPA)

Is there a way I could turn it into a `.deb` package?
I know `checkinstall` is used for things with a `make` but here that isn't the case. I was wondering if this is possible.

Comment: `checkinstall` doesn't need `make`. `make install` is what it typically runs, but you can use it with any command that copies files. And right from the first paragraph of [the manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man8/checkinstall.8.html): "checkinstall is a program that monitors an installation procedure (such as  `make  install`, **`install.sh`**)"

Comment: @N0rbert, I also wanted to ask this in general and not just with context to arduino.

Comment: In general it would be closed as too broad. Because the are to many softwares and too many combinations of files inside them. In Debian/Ubuntu there is a most universal way - use packages from repositories and other sources. See https://askubuntu.com/q/307280/66509 for the best details.